# Как реализовать принцип CQS?

Tags: c#

Уже 5 день пытаюсь реализовать данный принцип в Asp. net core, но все без успешно. Пытался прикрутить библиотеку mediatR , но с ней ничего хорошо не вышло. Не подскажете какие-нибудь примеры или готовые библиотеки для выполнения данной задачи, потому что я ничего найти не могу.

Comment: Пример: https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend

Comment: @A K, в данном примере реализован CQRS. Кстати, может у вас получится мне объяснить чем эти два подхода отличаются?) Вы товарищ с опытом) Я пытался найти инфу по CQS, но её крайне мало, а про отличия так вообще 2 слова обмолвят, а смылс так и не понятен.

Comment: @A K, медиатор хорошая штука, но у меня ни как не получается создать дженнирики для запросов и для комманд.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280756/5045688 CQS - микро-уровень класса/компонента, CQRS - макро-уровень контекста.